# Returning a single cell from an array formula

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to get a single value, the closing price, from this formula:

```
=GoogleFinance("NASDAQ:AAPL", "close", "12/13/2012",  1, 1)
```

Instead this formula populates 2 header rows (Date, Close) then two values (the date, and closing value $529.69).  Is there a way to get just the closing value returned and placed in the formula's cell?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the [INDEX](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs&tab=1240292) function:

`=INDEX(GoogleFinance("NASDAQ:AAPL";"close";"12/13/2012";1;1);2;2)`

Comment: Thanks for this. I've been trying to answer the exact same question for a whole day.