# Is there a way to have currency conversions from Google Finance stick?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy-paste, google-sheets-formula

I need to find a way to automatically copy the output of the below GoogleFinance formula into another cell and make it stick, i.e. doesn't change when the exchange rate changes.

```
=A1*GOOGLEFINANCE("currency:AUDGBP")
```

I was going to use something like `=value(x)` but this would change every time the above formula generated a new value, whereas I want something to stick as soon as it's output an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options, including:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (but could be tedious)
- GAS (with help for which SO expects some demonstration of effort on your part - or already answered)
- turn on iterative calculation (but in your case seems inadvisable)
- *perhaps* the [Spreadsheet Freezer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129211/how-do-i-install-spreadsheet-freezer) add-on from one of our esteemed members (I've not tried it)

Answer (score 1):

The GOOGLEFINANCE function has some optional parameters - one of them is the start date.

If you request the exchange rate for a particular date then it won't change later on.

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:AUDGBP", "price", "05/31/2019")
```

The output is a little different - a range with the date and value rather than a single cell, but the value for the exchange rate is correct and won't change.

You can then use the INDEX function to extract just the exchange rate

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE("Currency:AUDGBP", "price", "05/31/2019"), 2, 2)
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883933/returning-a-single-cell-from-an-array-formula)

Comment: This is great, thank you. It looks like I needed to replace 'price' with 'close' as it deals with historical data.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play with button and script then:

```
function moveValuesOnly() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                            var source = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1');
                            source.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet2!A1'), {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

which will copy the value from **Sheet1!A1** into **Sheet2!A1**

---

otherwise <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`C`**</kbd> and <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> +
   <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`V`**</kbd> for manual copy